# API Platform immutable property

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I'm using API Platform on a Symfony 4.3 project and I just want to have an immutable property (`userId` in this case) which can be set on POST but cannot be changed with PUT. So far, the only way to accomplish this was to drop the `userId` setter and use the constructor to initially set the value.

This setup still shows the property in Swagger for PUT (image below), but more troublesome is that it accepts that property without modifying the record. It's a silenced ignore and I would prefer a 400 Bad Request return code to let the client know his request was not processed as expected.

[image]

Is there any other way I could accomplish a similar behavior with API Platform? Already tried serialization groups, maybe with the wrong settings though.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\NumericFilter;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\SubscriptionRepository")
 *
 * @UniqueEntity("userId")
 *
 * @ApiResource()
 */
class Subscription
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     *
     * @ApiFilter(NumericFilter::class)
     */
    private $userId;

    /**
     * Subscription constructor.
     *
     * @param int $userId
     */
    public function __construct(int $userId)
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;
    }

    ...
?>
```

Comment: If `$id` is set by the application and not by the user you can look into serialization groups in the [documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#using-serialization-groups)
Can you show us what you tried with serialization groups?
On the other if the API needs to receive the `$id` you need to look for an input DTO, also in the [documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/dto/#using-data-transfer-objects-dtos)

Comment: It's the `$userId` in question, not the `$id`. If I use `normalizationContext={"groups"={"read"}}` (as per documentation) and set the `read` group on the `$userId`, it won't allow me to set the userId while creating a Subscription resource. I want to be able to set it when creating the resource, but not be able to change it via PUT.

Comment: I think you will need to explicitly set `normalization_context.groups` for `PUT` request to `{"read"}` (or something else, depending on your configuration). See [Operations documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#serialization-groups)

Comment: Thanks @IonBazan, missed that in the documentation. Feel free to submit your comment as an answer and I'll gladly accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need to explicitly set `normalization_context.groups` for PUT request to `{"read"}` (or something else, depending on your configuration). 
See [Operations documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#serialization-groups)